# Unable to set character encoding UTF-8 in .xhtml

Tags: primefaces, character-encoding, websphere-8

I have set the xhtml to UTF-8 and at ServletRequest. But it seems that it is still unable to detect the character encoding as UTF-8. I am working with Primefaces 3.5 with WebSphere 8.

.xhtml

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

RedirectLogin

```
public class RedirectLogin implements Filter {
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    if (request.getCharacterEncoding() == null) {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);

  }
}
```

web.xml

```
    <filter>
        <description>Redirect unauthenticated session to login page.</description>
        <display-name>RedirectLogin</display-name>
        <filter-name>RedirectLogin</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.belsize.servlet.filter.RedirectLogin</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>login_page</param-name>
            <param-value>/faces/login.xhtml</param-value>
        </init-param>


    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>RedirectLogin</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/RedirectLogin</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>RedirectLogin</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: You try to add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` to .xhtml header.

Comment: @RongNK I have that in the header in the .xhtml file too. But not working.

Comment: You mean: you can not use utf-8 format in your xhtml file or end user can not submit utf-8 format ?

Comment: @RongNK I can input chinese character but when I click on a button, the page will refresh. After the page refreshes, the chinese characters becomes some rubbish text.

Comment: You should the real issue, VietNamese is working fine.

Comment: @RongNK It seems ok now. I guess my environment is "dirty". After I clean my project, redeploy, its working fine now. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: You should post as answer, someone may be face this.

Comment: @RongNK I see. I'm new to stackoverflow, still trying to get used to it. But I still can't post as answer to my question yet as my reputation is not enough (: can only post as answer after it hit 8 hours.

Comment: This should actually be closed as "Too localized". There's no means of a real technical problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess my environment is "dirty". After I clean my project, redeploy, its working fine now.